# What is PWM about PWM DC voltage regulators?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to control the speed of a motor (220mA @ 5V) using a potentiometer, so I ordered two voltage regulators on AliExpress. My input voltage is 5V and I want the output voltage to be between 0 and 5V depending on the potentimeter setting.

[This](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005004734612297.html) is the first product and [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005005952654483.html) is the second product I ordered. I ordered two to simply be on the safe side.

In the second item it explecitely says:

> Enable to provide a continuous current of 2A to your DC motor or other DC load.

Both input and output seem to be DC, but in the title and description it also says something about PWM.

I know PWM from computer fans and I know what such a signal looks like, but the items I linked to have 2 input and 2 output pins. Both seem to be DC.

What is PWM about these two items?

Comment: Your links don't work.  It may be related to the way AliExpress reroutes to different domains depending on the source country of the web access.

Comment: @JRE I'm sorry the links don't work in your country. I also don't know if there is a way to fix the links. Perhaps the item is simply not available in your country.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "PWM" describes the switching regulator control scheme. The feedback is compared against a periodic ramp each cycle, which modulates the main switch on time based on load. This is in contrast to something like a fixed on or off time, skip mode, or even a hysteretic switching  regulator.

The output voltage should only vary by the cycle-by-cycle ripple and not dip too much, since the part is still regulating it through a closed loop.

If you want to think about it this way, the current into OUT (for a boost; for a buck the current into IN) is PWM, but the voltage stays regulated.

Comment: Those things are not buck converters. Or boost converters. Or any other type of smps. They do not have the inductor nor reservoir cap needed for those designs. They look to be simple PWM controllers, not voltage regulators.

Comment: @marcelm The provided links did not work for me when the question first went up; you're right that these are just PWM controlled with no feedback.  However, they're still switched mode power supplies, in the sense that they are switching to more efficiently deliver power to the load.  They also absolutely do have an inductor (the DC motor), and likely switch fast enough that the ripple current is relatively low.  They're an SMPS in the same way many LED drivers are.

Answer (score 0):

The output stage of each looks like this most likely:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVHTlg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By controlling the gate with a PWM signal you can control the average voltage going to the motor from near 0% to near 100%.

When the MOSFET is 'on', current flows from the power supply through the motor coils. When the MOSFET turns 'off' current flows through the diode and motor coils, so it's fairly constant for a given potentiometer setting (assuming enough motor inductance and sufficiently high switching frequency).

The second link looks better suited for 5V operation as the first one has 5V right at the limit of operation but both should work.

Answer (score 0):

PWM is a technique to drive a motor with pulses instead of constant DC voltage. Think of a fixed voltage and a switch that is toggled on/off. If you toggle fast enough but with different on/off interval, the motor speed follows the on pulse ratio.